# How to save user input in dialogue box?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am basically trying to create a dialogue box that takes user input text as a "Note" and it saves the note and shows the note the next time the dialogue box is opened, then the user can add on to the note or take away from the note and save it again. Thank you very much in advance.

Here's what I have so far:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(ViewTask.this);
alert.setTitle("Task Note");
alert.setMessage("Please enter your note");

// Set an EditText view to get user input 
final EditText input = new EditText(ViewTask.this);
alert.setView(input);
alert.setPositiveButton("Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
        String value = input.getText().toString();
        //String usernote = value;
    }
});
alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
    }
});
alert.setCancelable(false);
alert.show();
break;
```

Comment: Can you describe what isn't working?

Comment: Hi @Takendarkk , everything is working fine but I'm stumped on how I should save the user input and call it when the dialogue box is reopened. I was hoping for maybe a reference or a method name I can look into for some insight.

Thank you very much for your response.

Comment: Do you need to store it longterm? Like a user can exit your app then come back 2 days later and still see it?

Comment: Hey @Takendarkk , yes I was hoping to store it longterm. I think I'll need a database for that I believe? I'm not sure. Thanks a gain for your response.

Comment: Check this link --> [Android Storage Options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new String and assigning the value to it. After the user click's "OK" the String will be gone from the memory. Instead make a local variable in your class, and set it in the clicklistener

```
...
private String value;

...

alert.setPositiveButton("Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
        value = input.getText().toString();
    }
});
```

if you want it to be saved you can make the local variable static like this.

```
public static value;
```

Then you can have access to the value from all the classes by calling YourActivity.value. But beware that if you use the static method, the string will take space in the memory the whole time, until you set it `value = null`

Comment: OP states "_I was hoping to store it longterm_" As in, the user can close the app, wait a couple of days, open the app, and then still see the note. Your solution does not do this.

Comment: Opps, was a little to quick, didn't see that.. He can solve this by saving the value in the SharedPreferences. I see the link you posted already have a reference to it. Hope he manage to fix it :)

Answer (score 0):

Like Ibrahim said, you'll lose the String once your dialog has closed.
In order to perform more actions with it, like saving it to a database or saving to sharedPreferences, you should pass it back to the Activity that created this dialog, so that it can deal with that.

From [Passing events Back To The Dialog's Host](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#PassingEvents)

In your Dialog or DialogFragment class, add a public interface with a method that you will be able to call from the Dialog.

```
public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment{

    private DialogListener myListener;
    private String text

    public interface DialogListener {
        public void onDialogAction(String text);

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        // Verify the host activity implements the callback interface
        try{
            myListener = (DialogListener) activity;
        } catch(ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement DialogListener");

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        alert.setTitle("Task Note");
        alert.setMessage("Please enter your note");

        // Set an EditText view to get user input 
        final EditText input = new EditText(ViewTask.this);
        alert.setView(input);
        alert.setPositiveButton("Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                String value = input.getText().toString();
                myListener.onDialogAction(value);
            }
        });
        alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            }
        });
        alert.setCancelable(false);
        return alert.create()
}
```

Now you will have to change your calling activity to implement this callback listener we just created in MyDialogFragment

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
                      implements NoticeDialogFragment.NoticeDialogListener{

    private String text;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        SharedPreferences prefs = thist.sharedPreferences("com.example.app",
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        text = prefs.getString("text_to_save", "");
    }        

    ...
    public void showDialog(){
        DialogFragment dialog = new DialogFragment();
        dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "MyDialog");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDialogAction(String text){
        // Save the String for next time
        SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("com.example.app",
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        prefs.edit().putString("text_to_save", text).apply();
    }
```

And if you wanted to pass some data to you dialog, say the text you got from it before, you could implement this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17622679/1684866).