# Passing data from Fragment to DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, bundle, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to show a dialog when I get a Volley error and tell the user to retry again, so I choose a dialogFragment to be able to customize it.

I'm handling the error as follow in my Fragment class:

```
if (vError instanceof TimeoutError || vError instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),
                            Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getString(R.string.error_network_timeout),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if (vError instanceof AuthFailureError) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),
                            Objects.requireNonNull(getContext()).getString(R.string.error_network_auth_error),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if (vError instanceof ServerError) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),
                            Objects.requireNonNull(getContext()).getString(R.string.error_network_server_error),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if (vError instanceof NetworkError) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),
                            Objects.requireNonNull(getContext()).getString(R.string.error_network_network_error),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if (vError instanceof ParseError) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),
                            Objects.requireNonNull(getContext()).getString(R.string.error_network_parse_faillure),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
```

Actually I can only show Toast message per error type.

With the following, I'm trying to pass the message as an argument but doesn't seem to work.

```
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putString("vErr", "vErr");
DialogFragment errFragment = new NetworkErrorDialogFragment();
errFragment.setArguments(args);
errFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "NetErrDialogFragment");
```

Edit:
Retrieving the value:

In onCreateView of the dialogFragment:

```
errorTextView.setText(getArguments().getString("vErr"));
```

Comment: please paste that part of code where you are retrieving the arguments in the dialog fragment

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass data from a fragment to a dialogFragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17622622/how-to-pass-data-from-a-fragment-to-a-dialogfragment)

Answer (score 0):

Are your receiving at

```
 onCreate(){
 getArguments
}
```

of NetworkErrorDialogFragment?

Comment: no, onCreateView I set the textView message to getArguments().getString("vErr"))

Comment: not  advised but okay, can you debug inside onCreate

Comment: my dialogFragment doesn't have that method. I didn't override it

Comment: would it make any difference?

Comment: You tell me, anyway this is a very simple issue, do some debugging you will stumble into the issue

Answer (score 0):

DialogFragment uses onCreateDialog() method for creating a dialog and its content view. so you need to override this method and set an appropriate content view to it:

```
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Dialog dialog =new AppCompatDialog(getContext(), getTheme());
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.some_content_view);
        // retreiving arguments here
        TextView errorTextView = dialog.findViewById(errorTextViewId);
        errorTextView.setText(getArguments().getString("vErr"));
        return dialog;
    }
```